# is it good to "store" object in object

Tags: javascript, object

Is it better to store objects or reference to objects in an other object ?
Let me explain with an example.

I have one object "Team" and one object "Unit"
the unit belong to the team.
I want to "store" the object "unit" in my object "team".

1) I can do something like this : the *units* are stored in the team object

```
// class Team
function Team() {
    this.units = [];
}
// class Unit
function Unit(team) {
    team.units.push(this);
}
myTeam = new Team();
units = [];
units[units.length] = new Unit( myTeam );
```

2) Or something like this : the *units id* are stored in the team object

```
// class Team
function Team() {
    this.units = [];
}
// class Unit
function Unit(team, id) {
    team.units.push(id);
}
myTeam = new Team();
units = [];
units[units.length] = new Unit( myTeam, units.length );
```

is it understandable ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your concern is that storing objects will take up more memory, this is incorrect.

An object in Javascript is a unit of data stored somewhere in memory, but when you are adding objects in the first code sample you are merely adding a reference to that piece of memory: you are not creating a copy of the object (which would double memory usage).  There is no performance benefit in the second approach as far as storage is concerned.

Now, let us address design.  Many times, I have used associating arrays and the like, where the id of objects are not part of their set of fields.  This has invariably lead to more complicated code because there always came a time where I needed to pass the object somewhere but also its id.  Unless there are special circumstances that dictate otherwise,  it usually makes perfect sense that the id be considered to be part of the object.  A design decision that makes sense at the conceptual level is likely to lead to better design choices further on.

So my vote is definitely for alternative 1.

Comment: Yes, my concern was memory, and you perfectly answered it.

Answer (score 5):

Definitely go with the first, more object-oriented approach. I don't see any advantages of having ids and external array. But the disadvantages are obvious:

- external `units` array can be modified without you noticing, making ids out of sync and pretty much useless. Try debugging that!
- since there is no encapsulation, each `Team` can modify any `Unit`
- seems like one array stores references to all units, while only one `Team` *owns* the `Unit`.
- what will happen if you delete a `Team`?

  - if you don't delete all `Unit`s directly, you'll get memory leak
  - you might want to delete all its units from common `units` table. But this will leave gaps in `units` table.
  - if you delete units as well and compact the `units` array, you'll have to modify all other `Team`s as the indexes in the array will change
- id of `Unit` has no business value

Comment: Can I opt for leaving gaps? It doesn't seem so bad.

Comment: Note that each `Unit` can store its position in the `units` array so being able to reference into `units` is not a reason for storing IDs instead of references either.

Comment: @JanDvorak: thanks for your comments. Wrt. gaps it's not bad when you have an associative array, but without it the gaps will eventually consume most of the array. | Sorry, I rearranged some points, what do you mean by #2? Notice that if `Unit` also holds a reference to its index, there is one more place to update *if* you are compacting the `units` array. BTW feel free to add another answer if you see more advantages of global array, let the OP choose :-).

Comment: Clarified. While the `Unit`'s reference does need to be updated, at least now you know _where_ to make the change. That's why I vote for the first approach. Also `unit.ID` is much more readable (and much less common) than `units[unit_id]`

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz and can I also store the `team` object in the `unit` object ? thanks :]